# Not getting any output after running C++ code on VScode

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm new to C++ and VSCode. I ran my first program as given below.

```
// Your First C++ Program

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of Hello World being displayed in the terminal. The only message being displayed is :

```
PowerShell 7.4.0
PS C:\Users\iaman>  & 'c:\Users\iaman\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.18.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-mrm0mdrx.13w' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-5go0xtxz.qzq' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-c5ckjcsj.iwc' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-lzf3f1ks.4hc' '--dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi' 
PS C:\Users\iaman>
```

I don't understand what is that supposed to mean. Where am I going wrong?

I tried reinstalling MinGW but still the same problem. I checked my path variables and it is correct.  Please help as I've been breaking my head over this for a while now.

Comment: `C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe` It does not look like you installed MinGW using msys2 like the official VSCode documentation tells you: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: There could be several issues preventing you from output. Here are a few I think are likely 1) User Error, 2) Your antivirus could delete your executable before you get a chance to run it, 3) A cloud Drive like OneDrive 4) Having multiple versions of the MinGW runtime in your OS `PATH` environment variable where your OS finds an incompatible version of the runtime first in it search order. This last one is called [dll hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, the issue was not installing MinGW using msys2. I reinstalled it as given in the official documentation and it works correctly now. I'm receiving the output. Thank you!